# write an array of ints and chars to a file

Tags: c

I have three arrays, two of ints another of chars and Im trying to write them to a file.

My approach is the following:

```
FILE *file;
char *allinfo=NULL;
int intArrayOne[7];
int *intArrayTwo=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
char *charArray=malloc(5*sizeof(char));
.....
write into the arrays
.....

if((file=fopen("filename", "a+"))==NULL)
     printf("something went wrong\n");
else
{
     asprintf(&allinfo, "%d%d%s", intArrayOne, intArrayTwo, charArray);
     fprintf(file, "%s", allinfo);
     fclose(file);
}
```

The problem with this seems to be that the int Arrays dont write into the allinfo string. (The asprintf function allocates memory by it self by the way, if someone wonders). So how can this be done in a efficient way, I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%d` will print a single integer value, not an array on integers.  There is no format code that will print an array, you have to pass in each array element separately.

```
asprintf(&allinfo, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%s",
    intArrayOne[0], ... intArrayOne[6], intArrayTwo[0], ... intArrayTwo[9], charArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is `"%d%d%s"`, which is for a single integer, followed by a single integer, follow by a NUL-terminated string. There is no way for a `printf()`-style function to know how long your integer arrays are, nor is there any way to know where to end your string.

So you need to give seven `%d` flags for a seven-integer array. In practice, you'll want to loop over the elements of your array and call `asprintf()`.

As for the string, you'll need to ensure that it ends with `'\0'` before passing to `asprintf()`.